# converting time from hh:mm:ss to hh:mm in java

Tags: java, date, formatting

I want to convert time to hh:mm from hh:mm:ss
it comes from database (my sql) in the form of hh:mm:ss.
I tried the following code but i didn't get what i want.

```
 try {

        s= HibernateUtil.currentSession();
        tx=s.beginTransaction();
        Query query = s.createQuery("select from Dailytimesheet dailytimesheet where dailytimesheet.IdDailyTimeSheet=6083 " );         

             for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
             {                                                                           
                               if(it.hasNext())
                               {

                                   Dailytimesheet object=(Dailytimesheet)it.next();
                                   String dt=object.getTimeFrom().toString();
                                   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");  
                                   long ms=0;
                            try {
                                ms = sdf.parse(dt).getTime();
                                } 
                            catch (ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                                Time ts = new Time(ms);


         out.println("<h2>"+ts+"</h2>");
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: What answer did you get?  What answer *should* you have received?

Comment: You're missing a lot of brackets in this snippet - please format it correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert a `java.util.Date` object to a `java.lang.String` object representing the human readable time in the desired format using [`DateFormat#format()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29). You cannot convert it back to `Date` again (or any of its subclasses like `java.sql.Time` and so on) without losing the format. The format is namely not stored in `Date`. The `Date` only knows about the amount of milliseconds since the Epoch.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
java.util.Date date = object.getTimeFrom();
String string = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 4):

Converting HH:MM:SS to HH:MM is best done by `hhmmss.substring(0,5)` ;-) Alternatively, you may prefer to format the data right in the `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a new method to Dailytimesheet called getTimeWithoutSecondsFrom() which copies the date object and then sets the copy's seconds to zero before returning the date.

As an added benefit you can eschew the SimpleDateFormat sdf bit altogether then and the code will be easier to read.

The code might look like this:

```
public Date getTimeWithoutSecondsFrom()
{
    Date result = this.getTimeFrom();
    result.setSeconds(0);
    return(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about trying the java.util.Calendar Class?
You could do something like this:

```
Calendar c = new Calendar();
Calendar.setDate(new Date(object.getTimeFrom().toString()));
String date = Calendar.HOUR + ":" + Calendar.MINUTE
```

Or an I not getting your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `DateFormat`'s format method. Something like:

```
out.println("<h2>"+sdf.format(ts)+"</h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    String strDate = object.getTimeFrom().toString(); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do the conversion in the SQL in this case. Here is the MySql [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) on date conversion. In your case, it should be something like this -

> Blockquote DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i');

It looks like you are needing to do the conversion for each row you get from your query and it might be more cost effective to have it done by the database engine if you are retrieving many records.