# convert time variable to hh:mm format in java

Tags: java, datetime, time, timeofday

I'm a beginner in java and I with my code below I can generate a random time in `"hh:mm:ss"` format . I have no idea how to tweak my code to display time in "hh:mm" format as I am not familiar with the
Date and Time java libraries . I have checked posts here like [converting time from hh:mm:ss to hh:mm in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949699/converting-time-from-hhmmss-to-hhmm-in-java) but it does not help here .

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.sql.Time;
    
final Random random = new Random();
final int millisInDay = 24*60*60*1000;
Time time = new Time((long)random.nextInt(millisInDay));
```

I have also tried :

```
// creates random time in hh:mm format for 0-12 hours but I want the full 24 hour timeline 
public static String createRandomTime() {   
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("h.mm aa");
    String timeString = format.format(new Date()).toString();
    return timeString;
}
```

I would appreciate your help .

Comment: Use `java.time.LocalTime` here, it's better... But for now, change your pattern to 24h-format: `"H.mm"` without `a` for AM/PM. Hint: You are not creating a random time but return the execution time (of day) of the method.

Comment: `java.sql.Time` is hack on top of the already poorly designed `Date` class. `Time` was never meant for anything but transferring times to and from SQL databases. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class. All mentioned are long outdated. Avoid them. As @deHaar said, instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a method that creates proper random hours and random minutes, then construct a `java.time.LocalTime` of them and return a desired `String` representation.

Here's an example:

```
public static String createRandomTime() {
    // create valid (in range) random int values for hours and minutes
    int randomHours = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 23);
    int randomMinutes = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 59);
    // then create a LocalTime from them and return its String representation
    return LocalTime.of(randomHours, randomMinutes).format(
                            // using a desired pattern
                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
    );
}
```

Executing that method ten times in a `main` like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(createRandomTime());
    }
}
```

will produce an output like (not necessarily equal to)

```
08:16
07:54
17:15
19:41
14:24
12:00
12:33
11:00
09:11
02:33
```

Please note that the `int` values and corresponding `LocalTime` created from them will not change if you just want another format. You can easily switch the pattern to another one (maybe make the pattern `String` a parameter of the method). E.g. you could make it `"hh:mm a"` for `String`s like `10:23 AM`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `SimpleDateFormat`, I'd suggest taking a look to [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

In there, you can see that `h` is for hour in AM/PM format. Since you want the 24h format, you'll need either `H` or `k`, depending if you want it to be 0-23 or 1-24

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code,

```
public void testDateFormat() {
    String format = "HH:mm"; //24 hours format
    //hh:mm aa for 12 hours format
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

There is a fantastic Javadoc is available to explain the details of various options. Please refer the Javadoc as well https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: In spite of the OP's question, please don't encourage them to continue to use Date and its related classes.  Unless they insist, provide them a solution using the `java.time` package classes.